# Identifying jack socket contacts

Tags: components, schematics, datasheet, socket

Was just trying to identify the contacts on this jack socket (datasheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2047485.pdf )
Image of schematic below.
I was thinking that 1 would be ground? Which I guess would then lead 2/3 to be right/left? This may be totally wrong however, and I'd appreciate the help of anyone who can clear this up.
Thanks.

[image: Jack socket]

Answer (score 3):

It may help to realize that the schematic symbol for this connector is a representation of what's inside the physical connector:

[image]

Pin 1 is in contact with the sleeve of the plug, pin 2 is the tip, and pin 3 is the ring.

Answer (score 1):

The tip of the jack is the left channel (2), the ring (3) is the right channel and the sleeve (1) is ground.

Like this one:
[image]

Comment: Cheers for the help.